# Signature did not match on generated Azure SAS download link?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I've been trying to get the shared access signature working for Azure Blob Storage as I want to provide time limited downloads. For that I currently use a PHP script that calls a Python script on the Azure Websites service.

This is the way I call it to test things:

```
<?php echo "https://container.blob.core.windows.net/bla/random.zip?"; system('azureapp\Scripts\python azureapp\generate-sas.py "folder/file.zip"'); ?>
```

And this is the python script I use to generate the parameters:

```
from azure.storage import *
import sys, datetime

file = sys.argv[1]
accss_plcy = AccessPolicy()
accss_plcy.start = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-120)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
accss_plcy.expiry = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=15)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
accss_plcy.permission = 'r'
sap = SharedAccessPolicy(accss_plcy)
sas = SharedAccessSignature('containername', 'accountkey')
qry_str = sas.generate_signed_query_string(file, 'b', sap)
print (sas._convert_query_string(qry_str))
```

I managed to get this construct running for the most part, but my current issue is that if I use the link that was generated I am now always faced with this error:

```
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. 
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2015-01-27T22:52:17Z 2015-01-27T22:54:32Z /filepath/random.zip 2012-02-12
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

I double checked everything and tried to find something on Google, but sadly this aspect isn't really THAT well documented, and the error message isn't really helping me out either.

**EDIT:** forgot to leave an example link that was generated: https://container.blob.core.windows.net/filepath/random.zip?st=2015-01-27T23%3A23%3A18Z&se=2015-01-27T23%3A26%3A18Z&sp=r&sr=b&sv=2012-02-12&sig=eqCirXRjUbGGVVAYwWwARreTPr4j8wXubGx1q51AUHU%3D&

Comment: I don't see you adding the name of the blob container anywhere in your SAS computation. I just tried your code on my one of my storage accounts and the code worked perfectly fine.

Comment: In my local version I apply the container name right before getting the query string, e.g. `SharedAccessSignature('shopdownloads', 'accountkey---------------')`. I assumed that should be enough?

Comment: That is the name of the account. Assuming your container name is `bla` and file name is `random.zip`, change the following code from `<?php echo "https://container.blob.core.windows.net/bla/random.zip?"; system('azureapp\Scripts\python azureapp\generate-sas.py "folder/file.zip"'); ?>` to `<?php echo "https://container.blob.core.windows.net/bla/random.zip?"; system('azureapp\Scripts\python azureapp\generate-sas.py "bla/random.zip"'); ?>`.

Comment: That did it! Can't believe I looked for that tiny mistake for hours... could you post it as a full answer so that I can mark your answer as right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your container name is `bla` and file name is `random.zip`, please change the following code from:

```
<?php echo "https://container.blob.core.windows.net/bla/random.zip?"; system('azureapp\Scripts\python azureapp\generate-sas.py "folder/file.zip"'); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo "https://container.blob.core.windows.net/bla/random.zip?"; system('azureapp\Scripts\python azureapp\generate-sas.py "bla/random.zip"'); ?>
```

The reason you were running into this error is because you were not providing the name of the blob container in your SAS calculation routine, thus storage service was computing the SAS on `$root` blob container. Since the SAS was computed on a one blob container and used on another blob container, you're getting this authorization error.